# libcurl - LNK2019: unresolved external symbol curl_global_init

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, curl, linker, libcurl

I'm new to C++, and I've been struggling for the past 2 days trying to get libcurl to work. I'm on Windows, with VS 2012, and need to use libcurl for a x64 project. I have scoured the internet and SO for a solution that will help me, but not a single one has helped. I especially tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28266953/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-libcurl-visual-studio) link, which seemed to be the closest to what I need in the easiest possible instructions, and even that failed.

The error I am getting is a linker error, one for each call to any libcurl function.

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol curl_global_init referenced in function main
```

To clarify,

1. I have added libcurl/include to VC++ Directories -> Include Directories AND to C/C++ -> Additional Include Directories
2. libcurl/lib/static-debug to VC++ Library Directories
3. CURL_STATICLIB to C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions
4. libcurl/lib/static-debug to Linker -> Additional Library Directories
5. Full path to libcurl\lib\static-debug\libcurl_a_debug.lib to Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies.

Can someone please tell me if I'm doing anything wrong here, or if not, what on earth I can do to solve this? It's getting extremely frustrating, and I'm desperate.

Comment: If the Additional Library Directories are as you specified, and contain proper full path (or relative to the current project) to the libcurl libs of your desired libcurl build, then you need not specify a full path in the Additional Dependencies. Just libcurl_a-debug.lib should be sufficient.

Comment: I tried that too. Didn't help.

Comment: Same here, i've gone through 6 builds of curl now, none of them work